# In ngx-linkifyjs disable the Mention and Hash tag

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am useing

> ngx-linkifyjs

to convert url into the text to the URL with hyperlink. But along with the url it also converting # and the @ tags to the hyperlink.
How can i ignore # and @ and keep them as a text only.

PS: I read the documentation but could not found any solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import { NgxLinkifyjsModule } from 'ngx-linkifyjs';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, ...],
  imports: [NgxLinkifyjsModule.forRoot(
                  {
                    enableHash: false, // optional - default true
                    enableMention: false // optional - default true
                  }), ...],  
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

we can set **enableHash and enableMention** to false like above in the code snippet